# How to create and call temp table in redshift

Tags: temp-tables, amazon-redshift

I want to create a temp table and call this temp table in redshift? I have tried this one but got an error message.

```
select  top 10 * into #a from public.item_activity where item_act_timestamp < DATEADD(day,-1,getdate());

select * from #a
```

> "ERROR: 42P01: relation "#a" does not exist"

Answer (score 13):

Please create table table using command below below:

```
  CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table_name ....
```

Once this is done , use select query as below

```
  select * from temp_table_name
```

The temp table exists only for duration of your session using which you have created the table.

Comment: I tried this one

"create temp table a as
select  top 10 * from public.item_activity where item_act_timestamp < DATEADD(day,-1,getdate());

select * from a"

but got this error "ERROR: 42P01: relation "a" does not exist"

Comment: are u doing create table and select from temp table in same session ?

Comment: check here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html. Check for key work TEMPORARY | TEMP.

Comment: Yes,Sandesh. This is a small part of long script. The problem is in a long script I want to keep result from one query and use for others query. It is like step 1 2 3. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: So your script does not work in same session. I mean it uses more than one session ? In that case I guess you need to create sep table instead of temp table and drop it at the end of your script.

Comment: Thanks Sandesh, that could be the solution to solve this limitation.

Answer (score 5):

This problem vexed me for a while as well so posting solution even though the question was asked a while ago. The solution lies in the tool you're using, Aginity in my case, there are 2 ways to solve:

- Temporary solution for one query window and one query session: Click on Options-> Current Query Options -> Check box "Keep connection open between executions"
- More permanent solution for all query windows and all sessions: Click on Tools -> Options -> Query Analyzer -> Select "Keep connection open between executions" under Connection Handling

If you're not using Aginity, look for a similar setting in your tool.

Hopefully, I was able to help someone with this!

Comment: Useful information but I don't think this answer actually relates to the question, which was how to create and reference a temporary table in SQL.

Comment: The question was about temp tables on Redshift so it directly answers that question. As you can see from the original question, the SQL syntax is fine otherwise.

Comment: I must have missed the part where they mentioned using Aginity.

Comment: I voted this up because although I AM using Aginity and it fixed my problem, the answer doesn't assume the requester is using Aginity but states "The solution lies in the tool you're using".  Thanks for this answer, it solved my problem.  FYI in 2021 that option is a check box in the open tab (right next to the database dropdown).

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Create temporary table tbl_name as (Select * from abc)
--OR
create temporary table tmp_date_var AS
( SELECT '2017-04-01'::Date AS stdt,'2018-01-31'::Date AS enddt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `create table as` instead of `select into`.

Create temp table as:

```
create table #temp_table as
<subquery>
```

Query temp table as:

```
select * from #temp_table
```

For more, see: [how to create table in redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html).

Answer (score -1):

You are basically trying to store the result of your select query in a temporary table using the '**into**' keyword.
This can be easily done.
You just need to use **double hash (##)** before your table name.
So your query will now look like:

```
select top 10 * into ##a from public.item_activity where item_act_timestamp < DATEADD(day,-1,getdate());

select * from ##a;
```

Comment: By your use of `top` and `##` its obvious you think this is a sql server question.  It is in fact a RedShift question and neither of those key words are permitted there.